# Convert <img> to <img-amp>

Tags: image, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, amp-img

I'm working on nodejs & mongodb.
When I place this code; `<%- postContent %>`, it renders into the following format:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
<img title="Image Title" class="alignnone wp-image-9453 size-full" src="https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1.jpg" alt="image alt here" width="847" height="507" srcset="https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1.jpg 847w, https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1-300x180.jpg 300w, https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1-768x460.jpg 768w, https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1-825x493.jpg 825w, https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1-410x246.jpg 410w, https://example.com/images/2017/03/image-name-1-150x90.jpg 150w" sizes="(max-width: 847px) 100vw, 847px">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
```

Now, my query is; how to I convert `<img>` into `<amp-img>`?

Comment: You can try following the answer in this [amp-library thread](https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library/issues/173) where you "upgrade the fast-image-size package" using [this release](https://github.com/marc1706/fast-image-size/releases/tag/v1.1.2).

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to convert. You have to replace the img elements with amp-img elements.

And you have to use amp-img attributes src and layout, width and height with respect to layout.